# drupal 7 - programmatically disable block

Tags: drupal-7, block

How programmatically disable blocks under drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to code below. Points to keep in mind are for best usage:

1. Block must already exist and be assigned to a region e.g "before_content"
2. After each disable/enable clear your cache "drush cc all"
3. On re-enable the block remembers it's position
4. Your block delta can be a number only or alpha numeric

Disable block:

```
db_update('block')
          ->fields(array(
            'status' => 0,
            'region' => 'disabled',            
              )
          )
          ->condition('delta', 'client-block-number_here')
          ->execute();
```

Enable block:

```
db_update('block')
          ->fields(array(
            'status' => 1,
            'region' => 'before_content',            
              )
          )
          ->condition('delta', 'client-block-number_here')
          ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is why would you want to disable block? 
if you want to show a block depending on users, to do a db attack is not a good solution.

I think you can do that with region and preprocess system. A region can show anythings, blocks, text or **nothing**.

**Example :**

```
function HOOK_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook){
    //check the current user code...
    //..
    if (_condition_is_ok){
        $block = module_invoke('module', 'block_view', 'block_name');
        $variables["my_block"] = $block["content"];
    }
}
```

If you do that dont forget to check the variable is set in your tpl :)

I don't think that the better way to do that but it's better than use `db_update`, `db_update` write directly in your db, and by pass the drupal engine.

Comment: My particular requirement was based on a CRON job i.e. running on the server (scheduled). Worked perfectly.